# Unknown female pins - solder cups

Tags: connector, pins

I am trying to replicate a female connector by means of 3d printing, using my own pins.

This is the connector that I want to replicate:

[image]

Just the inside, not the circular part that surrounds it.
If you look at the metal pins inside, they are neither female pin connectors nor solder cups.

They are something else. When the male pin goes inside, they surround it. Perhaps they move slightly from the mechanical pressure

Does anyone know what kind of pins are inside and where can I order similar ones?

EDIT:  The male pin that I have (for which I want to find female connector pins) is `2.3mm` in diameter and `6mm` tall.

EDIT2: I am also not interested in getting the same exact receiver pin. Just something that will work. I just don't know the terminology, in order to search for the connector I want.

EDIT3: These are some female pins that I found in my workbench. The are nice, but smaller in diameter than what I want. If I knew their name in English, I could search for the same type but with larger diameter.

[image]

Comment: Could you post some dimensions?  Do you have a photo of the matching part?

Comment: @jonathanjo I updated the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> If you look at the metal pins inside, they are neither female pin connectors nor solder cups.

Actually, they are not pins at all: they are socket contacts. Specifically, they are fork type socket contacts. They are made for that particular connector. They are not likely to be sold because, other than you, the rest of us buy the complete connectors, not just the socket contacts.

Your best bet is to buy a female connector with fork type socket contacts and pull them out for your own use. Either the exact one in your picture (easily found on Amazon) or another one [like this one](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/7-215079-6/740376). The problem is that the vast majority of connectors use round socket contacts, not fork type. So, I recommend you consider using [round socket terminals](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/terminals/pc-pin-receptacles-socket-connectors/324) instead.

Comment: Thank you! Since the male pins are  `2.3mm` in diameter and `6mm` tall, what are the measurements of the female connector I should choose? I don't know what are the tolerances... For example, if the diameter of the male pin is `2.3mm`, how much fatter should its female counterpart be?

Comment: I also edited the question with a picture of some female connectors that I found lying around. Do you know how these are called? If I could find these in the dimensions that I want, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for adding the pin diameter. 2.3 mm corresponds to a "size 12" contact in MIL-spec parlance. Here are size 12 sockets for circular connectors: https://www.digikey.com/short/qn30rr49

Comment: Thank you very much! Now i have a name... Why are these so expensive though? $1 for the cheapest available pin? Can some of these be found that are NOT MIL-spec compliant?

Comment: As I said: "MIL-spec". There aren't many connectors for which you can buy round socket contacts separately and that specify the pin diameter. Rectangular connectors also let you buy contacts separately, but they are usually square (not round) and even when they're round it takes time to find out the pin diameter. As I said before, "They are not likely to be sold because, other than you, the rest of us buy the complete connectors, not just the socket contacts.". Your need is not one that the market has any reason to service.

Comment: Thanks again! And one more clarification please. Is it possible to find circular crimp connectors (I just found the name), like the ones i posted on my question as a picture?

Comment: The ones in your picture look like they were pulled out of a connector. If not, you can find just a few here (they're not common because there's little use for them): https://www.digikey.com/short/vtjtjb4b